Ubuntu 24.04 Suspends/hibernates from lockscreen even though suspend is turned off
I'm on Ubuntu 24.04 and i have turned off suspend
With
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

and
in Power settings and "privacy and security".
and it doesn't suspend when on desktop. BUT, when i set it to the lockscreen the screen turns black and after a wile the screen suspends and a wile after that the PC suspends/hibernates, this is where i get the trouble.
The pc is suspended and when i try to wake it it doesn't respond to any thing and i need to hard reset the pc for it to work again.
This is the problem i need to get around. I don't want the pc to suspend ever, not even on lockscreen, the screen can turn off but the pc should not suspend/hibernate since it won't wake up again.
Specs:

OS: Ubuntu noble 24.04 x86_64
Kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 7700X (16)
GPU: AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT


$ sudo gnome-control-center  - check whether the settings seen as root user affects the behaviour.

I had hopes this would solve it. But alas, it's still the same.
As root all the settings was turned to on, i disabled them and tried to lock, as usual the screen turned black, after a wile the monitor suspended and a wile later the pc hibernates and stops responding to input and a hard reset is needed. It seems the lockscreen is unaffected of the changes and only the desktop is behaving as it should. I changed setting in
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i "suspend\|sleep"

i'll return if this worked.

Check your system firmware is 100% current and if it is not, update it.

I have the latest firmware, still same, Locksreen hibernate my pc. I just can't wrap my head around this. If it worked the screen would go to sleep at most, but the pc should just not enter any other state.

I have the same problem.
What's your motherboard?
Mine is gigabyte aorus 550M elite v1.3

I have a 'PRIME B650M-A WIFI v1.xx' This problem torments me still. But atleast if i remember to not let it black on the lockscreen i can manually turn of my monitor but still quality of life is a huge deal.

As an experiment try turning off the battery charge saving algorithm as detailed in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1521574/closing-my-laptop-lid-for-several-hours-results-in-my-laptop-shutting-down-ubun/1521729#1521729 Answer 1 section 'Open6. Also see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/man5/systemd-sleep.conf.5.html for more details on this.

Experiment to show what hybrid-sleep actually does. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396970/is-hybrid-sleep-effective-in-case-of-battery-drain-restoring-session-and-open-p
