How to enable hibernate on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
I am struggling to set the hibernate mode on my Ubuntu laptop. I’ve been trying to suspend it, but it's not quite good.
I've tried several guides I found on the internet. I even tried ChatGPT but no luck there.
I am thinking that my Lenovo ThinkBook laptop does not support it for Ubuntu.
I would be grateful if someone could help me, as the hibernation mode is really convenient.

Please edit your question and paste the output of the command free -h in your question above. Does the Ubuntu installation have a swap file or a swap partition? Add that information to your question as well.

"Suspend" (set CPU to low power state)  tequires a modern CPU.  "Hibernation" requires a RAM-sized, contiguous swap area.

@ D'Hyena See the links pointed to by the following link answer: - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1521574/closing-my-laptop-lid-for-several-hours-results-in-my-laptop-shutting-down-ubun Be aware this will not work for a secure boot system due to kernel lockdown (also see link) as the kernel requires a encrypted swap space that it understands.

If your internal disk is encrypted follow this answer In any case you will need a swap partition or a swap file that is at least as big as the size of your RAM.

I'm using Ubuntu 24
follow this https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/1czkds9/ubuntu_2404_how_to_enable_hibernate_tutorial/
and here is the page for commands
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/
it works for me
Note: don't create new swapfile it willn't work only use the default swap.img and increase it's space. I tried with new swapfile it doesn't work

Thank you very much. I will try that and let you know.

Note : If it worked before and you just lost the hibernate button after upgrading to Ubuntu  ≥ 23.10 you just have to sudo apt install polkitd-pkla .
